# UITableView Cell repeating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I created a tableview with a custom cell showing data. The display works fine. But the cells are repeating so there are more cells being displayed then items in the array.

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
    // when searchcontroller is active, return the number of search results. If inactive simply return the count of the full AED list.
        return self.AEDItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.AEDItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell:CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        // Check if controller is active. If user is doing a search retrieve the aeds from the search result rather than the AED array.
        let aed = self.AEDItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.addressLabel?.text = aed.owner
        cell.objectLabel?.text = aed.street

        return cell
    }
```

Why is this happening? I guess it has something to do with the cell reuseage. But does the count of items does not solve it?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to verify any of your table view data source methods are being called?

Comment: Hm.. I would say they are used, as I can see the data correctly loaded from the network into the array and this data being displayed in the table view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this method:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
// when searchcontroller is active, return the number of search results. If inactive simply return the count of the full AED list.
    return self.AEDItems.count
}
```

This method is asking for the number of sections.  You should return simply `1` from this method.

Instead, you have as many sections as you do objects in your `AEDItems` array.  And then in your other methods, you're not putting any section specific logic.  So every section is identical to each other.  But we actually only want one section with many rows.

So, we actually want simply:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
// when searchcontroller is active, return the number of search results. If inactive simply return the count of the full AED list.
    return 1
}
```

Or, as *@johnpatrickmorgan* clarifies in the comments, we can omit this optional protocol method entirely, as `UITableView` assumes only a single section if its `datasource` has omitted this method.

For more reading, check out the [UITableView Data Source protocol documentation regarding `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:).

Comment: I just tried this. When I set the number to 1, it works not really... Because now, always the same data point is being displayed in each cell.

Comment: But I am not sure if this could be an error with the loading of the data from the network. I need to check this...

Comment: Yes... and also pay very careful attention to which method you are changing.

Comment: Oh.. now I see what you meant by being careful with the method. I changed the numbersOfRows to 1. Thank you!!!

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan You're right and wrong at the same time.  We *can* omit this because the default implementation of the table view itself (which is not the super class of our delegate) assumes `1` if this optional protocol method is omitted.  It has nothing to do with our datasource's superclass however.  [UITableView DataSource protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have only section. If it is one then Make it one only. If you have multiple sections and data for each section then use that data for each section

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
// when searchcontroller is active, return the number of search results. If inactive simply return the count of the full AED list.
    return 1 
    //return self.AEDItems.count
}
```

To experience Section, use below methods of UITableView

```
func tableView( tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String {

return "Section"
}

func tableView (tableView:UITableView , heightForHeaderInSection section:Int)->Float 
{
    return 20.0
}
```

I would suggest you to check this tutorial [Customizing Header and Footer of Table View in iOS8 with Swift](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning array's count for section that's why it is happening so please **return 1 section**.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
    // when searchcontroller is active, return the number of search results. If inactive simply return the count of the full AED list.
        return 1
    }
```